# Youtube auto play on click does not working

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have a script that I auto play a YouTube video now I want to open the YouTube video on click, Added on click event also add id onclick event but it does work for my any ideas.

```
/******************* HTML *********************/

  <div id="player1"></div>
  <button onclick="youtubevideo(Xc25RykxUrM)">Click me</button> 

 <div id="player"></div>
  <button onclick="youtubevideo(Xc25RykxUrO)">Click me</button> 

 <div id="player"></div>
  <button onclick="youtubevideo(Xc25RykxUrP)">Click me</button>
```

/******************* JQuery *********************/

```
<script>
function youtubevideo(videoIdval){

// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
  width: '100%',
  videoId: 'videoIdval',
  playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'playsinline': 1, 'origin': window.location.href },
  events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady
  }
});
}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
 function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.mute();
    event.target.playVideo();
   }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code, after making the following changes:

- In your `button`, the `video_id` should be closed with single-quotes.
- Changed the distribution of the code - following the [code sample in the docuemntation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en).
- Added a second `button` - for the sake of testing. Here, every time you click a button that calls the `youtubevideo` function, it will rebuild the YouTube Iframe and loads it with the `video_id` supplied.

Code:

```js
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  // This function seems to be needed, so, don't remove it from your code.
}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.mute();
  event.target.playVideo();
}

// Render the IFRAME once the button is clicked.
function youtubevideo(videoIdval) {

  // "Destroy" the "player" > for allow re-create it with the new "clicked" video_id.
  if (player != null || player != undefined) {
    player.destroy();
  }

  // Build the iframe with the "clicked" video_id: 
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    width: '100%',
    videoId: videoIdval,
    playerVars: {
      'autoplay': 1,
      'playsinline': 1,
      'origin': window.location.href
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
<button onclick="youtubevideo('Xc25RykxUrM')">Click me</button>
<br/>
<button onclick="youtubevideo('ouf0ozwnU84')">Click me # 2</button>
```

Here is the [running code on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSO2021/ty8ps7da/).

Comment: Three YouTube working only in single player. I want to each YouTube play individually